# elegant way to set tensor value according to a constant python list

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a const python list

```py
listA = [1, 2, 3, 23, ...]
```

and a tensor

```py
tensorA = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 23,...]]
```

Now I want to modify to `tensorA` according to `listA`:

> for each element `x` in tensorA, if `x` also in `listA` then keep it as it is, otherwise use the default value just like `-1`.

After this transformation, `tensorA` goes like

```
tensorB = [[1, 3, -1, -1, 23, ...]]
```

Is there any elegant way to do this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TensorFlow does not currently have anything like NumPy's [`isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), you would need to do an all-to-all comparison:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

listA = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 23])
tensorA = tf.constant([[1, 3, 5, 7, 23]])

isInList = tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(tensorA, axis=-1), listA), axis=-1)
tensorB = tf.where(isInList, tensorA, -1)
tf.print(tensorB)
# [[1 3 -1 -1 23]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension?

```
tensorB = [[n if n in listA else -1 for n in tensorA]]
```

Comment: thanks~but I want to know whether there is such operation in `tensorflow` based on tensor